# Validating dropdown

Tags: jquery, validation, drop-down-menu

Okay so I'm trying to validate my drop down with a custom rule and NOT wanting to do it inline because it needs to be a an integer value. Which means it can not have the Please Select An Option when submitted. So I don't know if I need to even make it disabled or how I should handle this.

```
<select id="sel1R3" class="chzn-done" name="sticky" style="display: none;">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select An Option</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT :** Now for some reason its not showing the validation error for the dropdown.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function (value, element, arg) {
    return arg != value;
}, "Message to User");

/*
* Validate the form when it is submitted
*/
var validateform = $("#newArticleForm").validate({
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        category: {
            required: true,
            {valueNotEquals: "-1"}
        },
        sticky: {
            required: true,
            {valueNotEquals: "-1"}
        },
        comments: {
            required: true,
            {valueNotEquals: "-1"}
        },
        datetime: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        status: {
            required: true,
            {valueNotEquals: "-1"}
        },
        file: {
            required: true,
            accept: 'png|jpe?g|gif'
        },
        permalink: {
            required: true,
        },
        article: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
            ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted.'
            : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted.';
            $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
            $('.box .content').alertBox(message, {type: 'warning', icon: true, noMargin: false});
            $('.box .content .alert').css({
                width: '100%',
                margin: '0',
                borderLeft: 'none',
                borderRight: 'none',
                borderRadius: 0
            });
        } else {
            $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
        }
    },
    showErrors : function(errorMap, errorList) {
        this.defaultShowErrors();
        var self = this;
        $.each(errorList, function() {
            var $input = $(this.element);
            var $label = $input.parent().find('label.error').hide();
            $label.addClass('red');
            $label.css('width', '');
            $input.trigger('labeled');
            $label.fadeIn();
        });
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var dataString = $('#newArticleForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'dashboard/articleSubmit',
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
                    $('.box .content').alertBox(data.message, {type: 'warning', icon: true, noMargin: false});
                    $('.box .content .alert').css({
                        width: '',
                        margin: '0',
                        borderLeft: 'none',
                        borderRight: 'none',
                        borderRadius: 0
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.box .content').removeAlertBoxes();
                    $('.box .content').alertBox(data.message, {type: 'success', icon: true, noMargin: false});
                    $('.box .content .alert').css({
                        width: '',
                        margin: '0',
                        borderLeft: 'none',
                        borderRight: 'none',
                        borderRadius: 0
                    }); 
                    $(':input','#newArticleForm')
                    .not(':submit, :button, :hidden, :reset')
                    .val('');  
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid_6">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/assets/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/document--plus.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" />
                <h3>Create a News Article</h3>
            </div>
                            <form  method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="newArticleForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">                    <div class="content no-padding">
                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" name="title" value=""  />                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="category">Category</label>
                        <div>
                            <select name="category">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please Select An Opion</option>
<option value="4">Columns</option>
<option value="2">Headlines</option>
<option value="1">Main News</option>
<option value="3">Rumors</option>
</select>                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="sticky">Is Sticky</label>
                        <div>
                            <select name="sticky">
<option value="-1">Please Select An Option</option>
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="comments">Allow Comments</label>
                        <div>
                            <select name="comments">
<option value="-1">Please Select An Option</option>
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="datetime">Date Comments Expire</label>
                        <div>
                            <input id="datetime" type="datetime" name="datetime" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="status">Status</label>
                        <div>
                            <select name="status">
 <option value="-1">Please Select An Option</option>
 <option value="0">Inactive</option>
 <option value="1">Active</option>
 </select>                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="file">Image</label>                            <div>
                            <input type="file" name="file" value=""  />                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="permalink">Permalink</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" name="permalink" value=""  />                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section _100">
                        <label for="article">Article</label>
                        <div>
                            <textarea name="article" cols="30" rows="5" id="article" ></textarea>                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End of .content -->

                <div class="actions">
                    <div class="actions-left">
                        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" id="reset"  />                        </div>

                    <div class="actions-right">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"  />                        </div>
                </div><!-- End of .actions -->
            </form>            </div><!-- End of .box -->
    </div><!-- End of .grid_6 -->
```

Any other ideas?

**EDIT :**

I've looked everywhere in the jQuery docs and can't find how to do this properly.

Comment: There was an answer here earlier and the person deleted it for some reason but I'm asking why is it not reporting the validation error for the dropdown.

Comment: This doesn't seem to need a custom method; you just need to use the rules for "integer" and "required", with an empty value attribute in the "Please select an option" option.  This will only pass if a) something is selected and b) that something is an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to specify your custom validation rule is like this:

```
category: {
    required: true,
    valueNotEquals: "-1"
}
```

That being said, you do not have to create a custom rule to deal with this.  Just use `required:true` and make sure the option value="" for your default option and jQuery Validate will take care of it for you.

I've created an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Rq9bn/) for you to look at, I changed the `status` dropdown to use the default method, and I've fixed your other references to your custom validation method to show it working (this is as @El Yobo suggested).  I also fixed a trailing comma in your permalink object (which will make the whole thing not work in a lot of IE versions).

Comment: What permalink object? Also I'm trying to figure out how I can do the permalink text box like say wordpress does where it takes out the spaces and puts dashes AND lowercases any uppercase letters and the like.

Comment: Sorry, the permalink definition in your validation call - it looks like `permalink: { required: true, }` with some extra new lines in there.  For your permalink replacement, you can use a regular expression to replace spaces with dashes, and the javascript String object has a toLowerCase() method that can do that part.  Do this in your `submitHandler` right at the top.

Comment: Well I was hoping to have it do it once I take focus off of the title box when there's been te t placed in the field

Comment: You can do that too if you prefer - do it in a `blur` event, I think?